# Silverlight XAP is getting shared across 2 session in the same machine

Tags: silverlight

I have a problem on my silverlight application.

I login in my application using my ID (assume x) (using Internet explore 8), 
so assume i can see some reports which is releated to my ID.

Without closing the above browser in another Internet explore 8 in the same machine i am login into the 
same application using another ID(assume y), so now i can see 2nd set of reports which is related to this ID.

Now If i refresh the report page of the first browser which is got logged with the ID (x), I am seeing the (y)
 userid's report not the earlier.

How to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In internet explorer choose "New Session" from the "File" menu.  This will create a new IExplore.exe process tree which manages its own set of session level cookies.  This should allow you to maintain two separate logins at the same time.

Comment: +1: As always, I learn something new every day... That is very handy to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using the ASP membership provider... if so that is limited to 1 session per browser/user on the same PC (same limitation if it was a web app).

Why are you trying to login 2 different users from the same machine? If it is for testing you can probably open two different browsers (IE and FireFox?) and get two session that way.

### Update (based on comments below):

**Option A.** As you need multiple user logins on the same machine in the same browser type, you cannot use the asp membership provider and will have to replace that provider with a Silverlight-specific credential/login system.

**Option B.** The alternative is to change your application to allow selection of client from within the app (this would be my choice as you are misusing *users* as a convenience).

Comment: No It is our requirement. Our application each user is for different client. So the admin login in differnt user id same time and confirgure all the client at a shot. So the requirement is like that. So IE and firefox idea will not help. Can you please suggest some way where i can open multiple IE in the same machine in differnt Usser id, but data should not be shared accross the browser

Comment: Our requirement is in multiple internet explorer in the same machine we should able to login with differnt user.
So each user information should not be shared accross